# How to create multiple payments in Stripe with an Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, stripe-payments, zapier

I have a list of Stripe clients emails in an Excel sheet.
I would like to create and execute one payment for each line of this Excel sheet.

How can I do that automatically? Is there any code or tool on Internet for that?

Here is the head of Excel sheet:

[image: Excel sheet]

Comment: Can you explain what parts of Stripe you are already integrated?  Do these emails correspond to Customers in Stripe?  Do you have saved payment methods configured for off-session use or will you need to bring users on-session to collect payment info?

Comment: Actually, I don't use the Stripe API, only the Stripe dashboard.
Yes, these emails correspond to Customers in Stripe. I already have their payment informations, and I can use them to create manually new payments via the dashboard.
But I would like to create these new payments automatically, based on my Excel sheet.

Comment: I don't believe there is a tool in the Dashboard to process this automatically.  How familiar are you with coding and using the Stripe libraries?

Comment: I am not very familiar with Stripe libraries, but I am a developer, so I can learn. How can I use them?

Comment: Stripe has libraries for 7 supported languages. Take a look here to get you started.
https://stripe.com/docs/development/quickstart